# Should I hire a mason to repair wall damage with incorrect brick?

Tags: repair, brick, masonry

A month or so ago I had an electrician in who accidentally put a hole through the brick wall of our house that now needs to be repaired.

From what I can gather, because I live in an older house the size of brick I need (11 1/4) along with the style is hard to track down. The job is also small so the first few masons I contacted weren't interested in making the repair.

Finally today I managed to find someone who offered to do the repair, but who also said:

> The new bricks are a couple inches shorter but will look better than this mess

So in my position, would it be the right course of action to just go ahead with the repair, or is it likely that I'll be able to make the repair with some semblance of invisibility?

Comment: Look for a salvage brick company in your area. Usual price would be from 40 to 60 cents a brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as a Waterproofer and Restoration worker I would call a local waterproofing company and ask if they have any guys that can do this type of work.  Personally if the brick is in a noticeable location I would pull a brick off a inconspicuous area and use it for the patchwork and replace it with substandard brick.